# Upload Text.txt file via Python + Create Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files, multiple-columns

I am a newbie when it comes to Python/Pandas.

I am able to upload successfully a text.txt file into Python with the following query.

[Raw Data - Updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7A8w.png)

[Raw Data - Updated2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0J11.png)

Raw Data

000001  0000    0001  001       X       1       01     1        1
000001  0001    0002  001       X       1       02     1        1
000001  0001    0003  001       X       2       03     1        1
000001  0002    0002  001       X       0       02     2        1
000001  0002    0001  001       X       2       01     1        1
000001  0002    0004  001       X       0       02     1        1
000001  0003    0005  001       N       2       03     1        1
000001  0003    0003  001       N       2       03     2        1
000001  0003    0006  001       N       2       02     2        1

```
df = pd.read_table('U:\\text.txt', nrows = 10, on_bad_lines='skip')
print(df.head())
```

The result comes up in one column, but I want to have them in multiple once.

```
print(df.head())
```

[image: Output]

So far I have tried couple of methods found here but nothing really worked. I have put few examples below.

```
.str.split("\s","") 

,sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')

,replace

**Few Examples**

df.columns = ["0"]                     
df = df["0"].str.split("\s","") 
print(df.head())
```

[image: Example1]

**OR**

```
df.columns = ["0"]                     
df = df["0"].str.split(" ", expand =True)
print(df.head())
```

[image: Example2]

**OR**

```
df.columns = ["0"]                     
df = df["0"].str.split(" ")
print(df.head())
```

[image: Example3]

Nothing seems to work. From my understanding it does not recognise the spaces between each content.

My ideal output is have a table with multiple columns to do analysis on it.

[image: Ideal Output]

Hope this helps.

Comment: remove screenshots and paste reproducible /executable code/data

Answer (score 1):

As I understood it correctly, you are using different deliminter among your txt file. You shoud set it as a space or a tab. Not both. Make it all the same and you might be good.

Comment: Those were just examples. Used them isolated, not in one query.

Comment: May I ask you why -1? You clearly had a problem with different spaces based on your conversation above